# Why Related Record component is displayed different with Profiles

Tags: data-views, view, standard, relatedrecord

I have 2 profiles: System Admin & Agent

In Opportunity record page there is a Related Record (standard Salesforce component). The way fields display is different from 2 profiles.

- I've check field-level security for `Agent`. This profile has read access to all the fields that are displayed with `System Admin`.

***This is what displays when using System Admin***

[image]

***This is what displays when using Agent***

[image]

- I also check the layout of View Opportunity. All the fields have been included here

[image]

- I also granted `edit` access as much as I can (only 2 fields cannot tick on view or edit checkbox) but the layout still displays the same as this post suggest.

Link reference: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000380203&type=1

Thank you so much